# What do these white on red words indicate on a London Heathrow taxiway chart?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, taxiing, airport-design

What do the words in white block capital letters over a red background denote on this aerodrome chart of LHR?

[image]

Comment: Could you source the image, please ?

Comment: @kebs http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadbasic/pamslight-A22138EF822CCA53AD188B9B368A7757/7FE5QZZF3FXUS/EN/Charts/AD/AIRAC/EG_AD_2_EGLL_2-1_en_2018-12-06.pdf

Answer (score 24):

They are named holding points; this allows them to say things like "taxi to RABIT" rather than "taxiway Bravo, hold short of taxiway Charlie". This saves a lot of time for ground controllers at busy, complicated airports.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning how these unusual names were chosen; https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1536531-ask-staffer-7.html

Comment: Thanks for that @Richard !  Intriguing they are FIVE LETTERS only.

Comment: @Fattie The reporting points or intersections in the air are five letters as well.

Answer (score 9):

It's the name of the holding points if ATC asks the plane to stop in the middle of the taxiway to avoid collisions